# CAML query to get all items which are 2 days from today

Tags: development, caml-query, caml

I have a site column of type Date and Time as follow:-

[image]

Now i want to query and get all items which have their Approve By exactly 2 days before Today. so let say today is *24 Sept 2020* then the query should return all items which have their Approve By = *22 Sept 2020*? can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="YOUR Approve By COLUMN" />
     <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="False"><Today OffsetDays="2"/> </Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: your CAML query worked but i need to use `2` instead of `-2`.. please update your answer so i can accept it

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: For future dates the value should be positive and for past dates negative.